# Alternate solution to "Determine if list contains two ints that sum to 0"

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Suppose you have an arbitrary list of ints, and return `True` if there is exists a pair in the list that sums to 0.

I was able to produce a solution in n*log(n) complexity. Here's a brief sketch (though there is a simpler way, see below):

1. Sort the array. Set a pointer to the first element.
2. Investigate pointer's element (call it first) and element at the opposite of the array (call it last). If the magnitude of the first element is greater than the last, remove the first element and move pointer to last element. Else start to iterate through the array backwards looking for the (possible) sum.
3. If didn't find the sum, move pointer to next element and Repeat 2.

The explanation above is not important. **Apparently there is another solution that uses dictionaries.** Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a simpler version of the n*log(n) algorithm is: 1. Sort the array by absolute value; 2. Traverse the array, checking whether `a[i] == -a[i+1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a sum of 0 if the elements are -x and x. Iterate through all the elements and store the values inside a dictionary. if you have an x check whether -x is set.

And btw, your solution is n*log(n)+n not n*log(n) `</nitpick>` :)

Comment: Isn't O(n*lg(n)+n) = O(n*lg(n))?

Comment: I am betting on @JuanLopes's comment.

Answer (score 1):

You add `key=n` and `value=0-n` to the dictionary. If the dictionary already contains `0-n`as key -> found the pair.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve O(n) time/space complexity by using a hashmap data structure.

1. iterate through all of the elements and put them to you hashmap (time complexity is O(n), taking into account, that amortized time complexity for hashmap operations insert, find and delete is O(1))
2. iterate through all of the elements and for each one check, if the hashmap contains the inverse value (i.e. for each value V check, if hashmap contains -V value). The time complexity is again O(n).

O(n) + O(n) = O(n)